# Airflow - View Failed Task Logs On UI

Tags: airflow

On the Airflow UI if you have a task that fails is it possible to view logs specific to that task from within the UI?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on the task rectangle of `custom_file_sensor_test_1_OmegaFileSensor` with the red border within the graph -> `View log`.

The same is possible within `Tree View`. I find `Tree View` a bit more accessible, since you don't need to select the correct date as in comparison to the `Graph View`.

It is also possible to access the logs from the main screen. In the `Links` section, the hamburger-like icon to the right (v1.9.0) also leads to the logs.